# JoomSEF extension not create SEF URL on page visit

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, non-sef-url

I am using free version of JoomSEF extension. When I visit any page, JoomSEF extension is not creating according SEF URL entry in the backend. It looks something minor but I am clueless for this.

If I manually run URL like http://mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1098&Itemid=105 then it creates SEF URL in the backend but this is not feasible for me. The extension should create entry when I visit any page.

If I run URL [http://mywebsite.com /news/gathering-in-glasgow-in-conflict-and-faith](http://%20http://mywebsite.com%20/news/gathering-in-glasgow-in-conflict-and-faith) it gives me an error like **"404- Article not found"**. I also  reinstalled the extension several times but it didn't work either.

It was working nicely before the latest Joomla version and JoomSEF upgrade.

Alternative solution is also fine to me. I just need site running. That's it.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Joomla: Joomla! 3.9.8 Stable 
JoomSEF: 4.7.6
PHP Version: 5.6.40
```